# Googlemap api custom control

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to use a custom control on a Google map. I've tried [code sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) from Google documentation. But i would like : on click event scroll window to position 0,0...

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(img, 'click', function () { alert('yy'); window.scrollTo(0, 0); });
```

the alert is fired but not scrolling... someone have any ideas ..?

thank

Comment: Do you want to replace your MAP at coordinates 0,0 at click event, or do you want to go to the top of your webpage ?

Comment: what is `img`? what is width and height of your map?

Comment: i just want to go on the top of my webpage img is an image in my custom control div. the height of my map is calculate with window.innerHeight

Comment: i'm stupid !!! my map was in a frame without that it's working well thanks